# JQuery toggle div inside the foreach loop

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, knockback.js

I am using knockback.js.I have a list of values "projects"(value comes from the server). and the content of these values are displayed in the   `<div  class="hiddendivcontent">` .

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: projects" class="list-group">

     <li class="list-group-item" data-bind="click: function(data,event){CommunityView.showContents($data.pkey(),$data.folder(), data, event);}">
          <span style="border:0px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus pull-right" data-toggle="dropdown" ></span>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu labellistdropdown" role="menu" style="min-width:200px;">
              <li>..</li>
          </ul>
          <div  class="hiddendivcontent">
              <ul data-bind= "foreach : $root.community()" class="list-group">
                   <ul data-bind = "foreach :items">
                     <li> <span data-bind="text:cname"></span></li>
                   </ul>   
              </ul>
           </div>    
    </li>  

 </ul>
```

The "hiddendivcontent"  gets the value when "CommunityView.showContents()" is clicked. In other words,"hiddendivcontent" should be displayed when the method is clicked otherwise it remains hidden. The following code is the Jquery code that i have used :

```
showContents : function(pk,rf,data,event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $('.hiddendivcontent').toggle(); 
    }
```

If I use this above code the value is populated in all the list items. I have tried many ways to toggle the div but nothing works. Can anyone please suggest me any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would be really helpful, if you'd create a simple jsfiddle with the exact issue you have.

Comment: Another thing - in your `click` binding you pass arguments `$data.pkey(),$data.folder()`, but should be `data.pkey(),data.folder()`, because `$data` is undefined in context of anonymous function.

Comment: There is no problem in that. I have checked it with alert messages in js part. My problem is toggling the hiddendivcontent for each and every list item

Comment: You're right, I thought that won't work. But jsfiddle would still be nice.

Comment: But to do in jsfiddle i dnt know how to populate values for foreach:projects values. I m new to this. so i dnt know how to proceed in jsfiddle

Comment: Create some dummy object, cut all unnecessary properties and markup leaving only the part where the issue persists. Ideally this would be a small piece of code with exact issue you're experiencing.

Comment: Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/3v4rmfwg/

Comment: In your code, can you add properties to `projects` before putting them on page?

Comment: I couldnt understand your question. The projects values are got from the server and displayed on the webpage

Answer (score 1):

Try using knockout [visible](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/visible-binding.html) binding. First, when receive your projects from server, add to each project `isVisible` observable:

```
$.get(..., function(projects){
    projects = $.map(projects, function(project) {
        project.isVisible = ko.observable(false);
        return project;
    });
    viewModel.projects = projects; // assign received projects to your view model
});
```

Now in your markup use `visible` binding as follows:

```
<div data-bind="visible: isVisible">
    <ul data-bind= "foreach : $root.community()" class="list-group">
        <ul data-bind = "foreach :items">
            <li> <span data-bind="text:cname"></span></li>
        </ul>   
    </ul>
</div>
```

Note that you don't need `hiddendivcontent` class anymore. Last thing, in your `showContents` do as follows:

```
showContents: function(name, id, data, event) {
    data.isVisible(!data.isVisible());
}
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/03mtt6ez/). I hope that's what you needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I tried it another way and it worked. Here is my improved answer. http://jsfiddle.net/usezpkj2/4/

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer for my question.

I have added some bootstrap icons for the list. So when the user clicks on the bootstrap glyphicon the hidden ul(which is created dynamically everytime when a user clicks on it) should be shown.

```
$(".glyphicon ").click( function ( e ){ 
   e.preventDefault() // prevent default action - hash doesn't appear in url
    var target = $(e.target);
    if(target.hasClass("glyphicon-chevron-right")){
    $(e.target).toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-right glyphicon-chevron-down');
    var $newList = $("<ul />");
        $newList.append("<ul class="+"hiddendivcontent"+">");
    for(var i = 1; i <=4; i++) {
        $newList.append("<li><span>" + "menu" + i + "</span></li>");
    }        
    $(this).closest("li").append($newList);
    }
    else if(target.hasClass("glyphicon-chevron-down")){
         $(e.target).toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-right glyphicon-chevron-down');
        $(e.target).parent().find("ul").remove();
    }
} )
```

http://jsfiddle.net/usezpkj2/4/